# Moving Average in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below table with values:

```
Row_ID FQFY       Average
1      2018-Q1    70%
2      2018-Q2    60%
3      2018-Q3    50%
4      2018-Q4    90%
5      2019-Q1    70%
6      2019-Q2    80%
7      2019-Q3    20%
8      2019-Q4    NULL
9      2020-Q1    30%
```

Starting from 4th row, I have a requirement to calculate the moving average of preceding 4 row values. And if there is any `NULL` value, then the requirement is to ignore this `NULL` while doing the average

Can someone please help me here with the code in SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `AVG` with an appropriate window frame:

```
SELECT *, AVG(Average) OVER (ORDER BY FQFY ROWS BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) rollingAverage
FROM yourTable;
```

Regarding the `NULL` requirement, `AVG` by default already ignores `NULL` values.